# How to check reflect.Value is nil or not?

Tags: go, null, reflect

I have this code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)


type cmd struct{
    Echo func(string) (string,error)
}



func main() {
    cmd := cmd{
        Echo : func(arg string) (string, error) {
            return arg, nil
        },
    }
    result := reflect.ValueOf(cmd).FieldByName("Echo").Call([]reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf("test")})
    if result[1] == nil{
        fmt.Println("ok")
    }
}
```

I want to check if my error is nil, but in my code, it doesn't work cuz it has different types. I try to make like this :

```
reflect[1] == reflect.Value(reflect.ValueOf(nil))
```

So it has the same type but the value of `reflect.Value(reflect.ValueOf(nil))` isn't nil, it is `<invalid reflect.Value>`.

Comment: To get the actual value that's stored in `reflect.Value` you can use the `.Interface()` method. https://play.golang.com/p/42fVZLqYtV3. The docs: https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `.IsNil()` to check whether the value that's stored in `reflect.Value` is `nil`.

```golang
if result[1].IsNil() {
   fmt.Println("ok")
}
```

Or you can use `.Interface()` to get the actual value that's stored in `reflect.Value` and check whether this is `nil`.

```golang
if result[1].Interface() == nil {
    fmt.Println("ok")
}
```

Comment: The instruction `fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(nil).IsNil())` result in a panic displaying the message "panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.IsNil on zero Value". Strangely, the method call IsZero() also panics with the message "panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.IsZero on zero Value". Once I have a reflect.Value of nil, it seam that there is no test to detect this.

Comment: you may use `reflect.ValueOf(nil).IsValid()` which, given the doc, `returns false if v is the zero Value.`

Comment: `if result[1].Interface() == nil {` this won't work if interface is a nil pointer btw, it only works if both type and interface of interface is nil